# Loop through an array onsubmit

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to loop through an array so that each time the form is submitted the character in the array is incremented so that each person in the world receives a character that is incremented from the person who has previously used the form. How do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
</script>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Country:
<select name="country">
<option value="A">America</option>
<option value="B">Germany</option>
<option value="C">Greece</option>
<option value="D">Russia</option>
<option value="E">UK</option>
</select><br>
Postcode:
<input type="text" name="postcode">
<input type="submit">
</form><br>
Your number is:
<?php
$place = array("T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
$person = "number";
$i = 0;
echo $_POST["country"] . $_POST["postcode"] . $place[$i] . $person; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need to store the previous value somewhere first, most probably in a database

Comment: This is probably better done with JavaScript (and AJAX if server side code is required), and also your definition of `$i = 0;` will cause it to only ever echo `T` for `$place`.

Comment: if you store them in a database, the database will do the increment for you